# I keep on receiving a "bash permission denied" notification every time I try to execute a program on VS Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, terminal, visual-studio-2012, permission-denied

No matter what program I try to execute, VS code won't allow me to. It was working great before.

I tried `$ ./name` of my programs (I tried with various, of course)
and I receive a `bash: permission denied` error every time.
Now it is also replying with wrong errors when I try to execute anything.

Comment: You're gonna need to add some actual information to this question.

Comment: If it used to work but now it doesn't work, you should aim to identify what you changed, and reset it back to the prior setting.  But it is going to be hard to help without a lot more information.  Are you sure you shouldn't (couldn't) be using a more recent system than VS 2010 or VS 2012?  They are pretty old.

Comment: You mention VS Code but you added tags for VS. Actually, you added even 2 different versions of VS. VS and VSCode are very different things. Which one do you use? As you seem to use bash, I would assume it is about VS Code. correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your question must be more detailed.
But I try to suppoze:
you didn't compile your program.
If your code don't have any mistakes you can compile your program using code below:

```
cc name_file.c
```

or

```
gcc name_file.c
```

After that.. you will see new file in the folder where located name_file.c compiled file, like this:

```
a.out
```

And you should launch it:

```
$./a.out
```